# Как в node.js, по пути к файлу из переменной, вывести страничку содержимое файла?

Tags: javascript, node.js

На страничке /create в форме я ввожу в форму  полный путь к файлу, получаю путь и закидываю в переменную text, после по этому пути считываю содержимое файла на корневой страничке. Но у меня не получается прочитать путь из переменной. Подскажите кто как может!)

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var text = '';

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index', { text: text}));

app.get('/create', (req, res) => res.render('create'));
app.post('/create', (req, res) => {
  text = req.body.text;
  console.log(req.body);
  res.redirect('/');
});

fs.stat('/home/devoid/test.txt', (err, stats) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
  console.log(stats.isFile()) //true
  console.log(stats.size) //1024000 //= 1MB
  })
  
fs.readFile(text, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
  console.log(data)
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="/create">Add</a>
  
    <p><%= text %></p>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А чему равен `text` перед тем, как вы пытаетесь его вставить в `fs.readFile`? Выведите в консоль

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov :  Опечатка в имени файла обраружилась..